# 'System.ValueTuple<bool,string,string,string,string>' does not contain a definition for 'addedcontactmail'

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I get this error message in my Azure function:

> 'System.ValueTuple<bool,string,string,string,string>' does not contain a definition for 'addedcontactmail'

```
namespace My.Functions
{
    public class Result
    {
        public bool FunctionSuccessful { get; set; }
        public string Errorline1 { get; set; }
        public string Errorline2 { get; set; }
        public string Errorline3 { get; set; }
        public string Errorline4 { get; set; }
    }

    public static class NewFunction
    {
      [FunctionName("MyNewFunction")]
    public static async Task<dynamic> NewCall(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
        {
        var context = await FunctionContext<dynamic>.Create(req);
        var args = context.FunctionArgument;

        bool functionsuccessful = false;
        string errorline1 = string.Empty;
        string errorline2 = string.Empty;
        string errorline3 = string.Empty;
        string errorline4 = string.Empty;

        var resultcontactemail = await AddContactEmail(desiredemail, language, clientAPI);
        if (resultcontactemail.addedcontactmail == false)
        {
            functionsuccessful = resultcontactemail.addedcontactmail;
            errorline1 = resultcontactemail.errorline1;
            errorline2 = resultcontactemail.errorline2;
            errorline3 = resultcontactemail.errorline3;
            errorline4 = resultcontactemail.errorline4;
            return new Result
            {
                FunctionSuccessful = functionsuccessful,
                Errorline1 = errorline1,
                Errorline2 = errorline2,
                Errorline3 = errorline3,
                Errorline4 = errorline4
            };
        }
    
        }

    public static async Task<(bool addedcontactmail, string errorline1, string errorline2, string errorline3, string errorline4)> AddContactEmail(this string emailaddress, string language, PlayFabClientInstanceAPI clientAPI)
    {
        bool addedcontactmail = false;
        string errorline1 = string.Empty;
        string errorline2 = string.Empty;
        string errorline3 = string.Empty;
        string errorline4 = string.Empty;

        var request = new PlayFab.ClientModels.AddOrUpdateContactEmailRequest();
        request.EmailAddress = emailaddress;
        var result = await clientAPI.AddOrUpdateContactEmailAsync(request);

        if (result.Error != null)
        {
            var errors = OnPlayFabError(result.Error, language);
            errorline1 = errors[0];
            errorline2 = errors[1];
            errorline3 = errors[2];
            errorline4 = errors[3];
        }
        else
        {
            addedcontactmail = true;
        }
          return (addedcontactmail, errorline1, errorline2, errorline3, errorline4);
    }

    }
}
```

Is something wrong with the following line of code?

```
 functionsuccessful = resultcontactemail.addedcontactmail;
```

"addedcontactmail" and "functionsuccessful" are bool, why is it not working?

I want that "functionsuccessful" gets the value of "resultcontactemail.addedcontactmail", it can be true or false.

What exactly is wrong?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood how Tuples work. Your tuple is unnamed, so you can't just access it like that; you need to unpack it first. I recommend you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: I don't understand how to use Tuples in my code so that I can assign the value of addedcontactmail to functionsuccessful.

Comment: You should read the link I posted, it shows you how to unpack tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `AddContactEmail` function call correctly, because it is an **extension** of string. Check out below code, that I have tested in my local and works fine:

```
[FunctionName("MyNewFunction")]
        public static async Task<dynamic> NewCall(
          [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", "get", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
        {
            //var context = await FunctionContext<dynamic>.Create(req);
            //var args = context.FunctionArgument;

            bool functionsuccessful = false;
            string errorline1 = string.Empty;
            string errorline2 = string.Empty;
            string errorline3 = string.Empty;
            string errorline4 = string.Empty;

            var resultcontactemail = await desiredemail.AddContactEmail(language, clientAPI);
            if (resultcontactemail.addedcontactmail == false)
            {
                functionsuccessful = resultcontactemail.addedcontactmail;
                errorline1 = resultcontactemail.errorline1;
                errorline2 = resultcontactemail.errorline2;
                errorline3 = resultcontactemail.errorline3;
                errorline4 = resultcontactemail.errorline4;
                return new Result
                {
                    FunctionSuccessful = functionsuccessful,
                    Errorline1 = errorline1,
                    Errorline2 = errorline2,
                    Errorline3 = errorline3,
                    Errorline4 = errorline4
                };
            }

            return null;
        }

        public static async Task<(bool addedcontactmail, string errorline1, string errorline2, string errorline3, string errorline4)> AddContactEmail(this string emailaddress, string language, PlayFabClientInstanceAPI clientAPI)
        {
            bool addedcontactmail = false;
            string errorline1 = string.Empty;
            string errorline2 = string.Empty;
            string errorline3 = string.Empty;
            string errorline4 = string.Empty;

            var request = new PlayFab.ClientModels.AddOrUpdateContactEmailRequest();
            request.EmailAddress = emailaddress;
            var result = await clientAPI.AddOrUpdateContactEmailAsync(request);

            if (result.Error != null)
            {
                var errors = OnPlayFabError(result.Error, language);
                errorline1 = errors[0];
                errorline2 = errors[1];
                errorline3 = errors[2];
                errorline4 = errors[3];
            }
            else
            {
                addedcontactmail = true;
            }
            return (addedcontactmail, errorline1, errorline2, errorline3, errorline4);
        }
```

Comment: It's not working. I get an error message in this line: var resultcontactemail = await desiredemail.AddContactEmail(language, clientAPI); 'string' has no applicable method named 'AddContactEmail' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Weird, did you change anything? Because this works in my local.

Comment: I have copy&paste your code but it's not working. I always get the error message in line:   var resultcontactemail = await desiredemail.AddContactEmail(language, clientAPI);

Comment: Can you try removing `clientAPI` from extension method definition and call?